# How to decide the dependency list for React.useCallback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Consider the following example where the `resetCount` function can work correctly with an empty dependency list as well.

So, should we include `setCount` in its dependency?
Are there any guidelines to keep in mind?
I am interested to know the guidelines for the dependency list in React.useCallback.

```js
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import Child from "./Child";
import './style.css';

const Parent = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  console.log("re-render parent component");

  const resetCount = useCallback(() => {
    setCount(0);
  }, [setCount]); // ([] as well as [setCount] - both work) So should this dependency contain setCount? 

  return (
    <main>
      <p>Count: {count}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count=>(count+1))}>Increment</button>
      <Child reset={resetCount} />
    </main>
  )
}

render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the most definitive advice (and the best starting point for not so advanced React programmers) is: [*Don't lie to React about dependencies*](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#dont-lie-to-react-about-dependencies). With that, it will always work as expected, and you won't get any surprise.

Now you can make exceptions to that rule, if you know that something won't change. For the set state function returned by the `useState` hook, this is the case, so you *can* omit it, yet there is no harm done in leaving it there (cause as it does not change, it won't cause the effect to trigger).

Comment: So can I say the empty dependency would be more efficient? That way React would never check whether the dependency elements changed or not.

Comment: No, not really. That one comparison more will have no impact whatsoever. I do omit those for brevity (and to make clear which dependencies do actually change), I never do that for performance reasons.